# Why the player is stuttering after moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DetectCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform target;
    public Text currPosDistanceUiText;
    public bool rotateAutomatic = false;
    public bool turnOnOffPlayerAnimator = false;

    float timeElapsed = 0;
    float lerpDuration = 3;
    float startValue = 1;
    float endValue = 0;
    float valueToLerp = 0;

    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private bool entered = false;
    private bool prevFacing = false;
    private bool stopped = false;
    private bool move = true;
    private bool rot = false;
    private Vector3 currPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerAnimator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();

        if (turnOnOffPlayerAnimator)
            playerAnimator.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var currFacing = IsFacing(target);
        if (currFacing != prevFacing)
        {
            // here you switched from facing to not facing or vise verca.
            timeElapsed = 0;
        }
        prevFacing = currFacing;

        var distance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, target.position);

        if (IsFacing(target))
        {
            if (entered && distance > 30 && move)
            {
                if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
                {
                    valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                    playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                    timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
                }
                playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                stopped = true;
                valueToLerp = 0;
            }

            if (move == false)
            {
                playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", 0);
            }

            if (playerAnimator.GetFloat("Forward") == 0 && stopped)
            {
                move = false;
                rot = true;
                currPos = player.position;
                
                Debug.Log("Player current position when valueToLerp value is 0 : " + currPos);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (rotateAutomatic == false)
            {
                if (valueToLerp < 0.9f)
                {
                    if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
                    {
                        valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(endValue, startValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                        playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
                    }
                    playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                }
            }

            var dist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, currPos);
            currPosDistanceUiText.text = dist.ToString();
            if (dist > 2)
            {
                move = true;
            }
        }

        if (rotateAutomatic && rot)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ScaleOverSeconds(new Vector3(0.3f,0.3f,0.3f),
                new Vector3(0,90,0), new Vector3(player.localPosition.x + 20,0,0) , 5));
            rot = false;
            //StartCoroutine(AnimateRotationTowards(player, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0), 5f));

            /*player.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(player.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0), Time.time * 0.0003f);

            if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
            {
                valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(endValue, startValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            }
            playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);*/
        }

        if (turnOnOffPlayerAnimator)
        {
            playerAnimator.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            playerAnimator.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        entered = true;

        Debug.Log("Entered !");
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        entered = false;

        Debug.Log("Exited !");
    }

    private bool IsFacing(Transform target)
    {
        Vector3 forward = player.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 toTarget = target.position - player.position;
        return Vector3.Dot(forward, toTarget) > 0;
    }

    private System.Collections.IEnumerator AnimateRotationTowards(Transform target, Quaternion rot, float dur)
    {
        rotateAutomatic = true;
        float t = 0f;
        Quaternion start = target.rotation;
        while (t < dur)
        {
            target.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(start, rot, t / dur);
            yield return null;
            t += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        target.rotation = rot;
    }

    public IEnumerator ScaleOverSeconds(Vector3 scaleTo, Vector3 rotateTo, Vector3 moveTo, float seconds)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0;
        Vector3 startingScale = player.localScale;
        Vector3 startingRotation = player.localEulerAngles;
        Vector3 startingPosition = player.localPosition;
        
        while (elapsedTime < seconds)
        {
            player.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startingScale, scaleTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));
            player.localEulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(startingRotation, rotateTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));
            player.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startingPosition, moveTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));

            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            
            yield return null;
        }
        player.localScale = scaleTo;
        player.localEulerAngles = rotateTo;
        player.localPosition = moveTo;
    }   
}
```

I'm setting rot to true on line 73.

Then

```
public IEnumerator ScaleOverSeconds(Vector3 scaleTo, Vector3 rotateTo, Vector3 moveTo, float seconds)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0;
        Vector3 startingScale = player.localScale;
        Vector3 startingRotation = player.localEulerAngles;
        Vector3 startingPosition = player.localPosition;
        //If you want, you can change axis of rotation or angle or everything you want. But what I do - I rotate by Y-axis for 180 degrees

        while (elapsedTime < seconds)
        {
            player.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startingScale, scaleTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));
            player.localEulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(startingRotation, rotateTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));
            player.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startingPosition, moveTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));

            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            
            yield return null;
        }
        player.localScale = scaleTo;
        player.localEulerAngles = rotateTo;
        player.localPosition = moveTo;
    }
```

It's scaling , rotating , moving all the same time but for some reason at the end when its finishing moving the player is stattuering on place.

It was working fine when in the ScaleOverSeconds it was with scaling and rotating only the stuttering at the end started after adding the moving part.

The player have attached this components :

[player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WUFU.jpg)

and this gameobject is a quad and this is the entering area detection when the player enter and this script is attached to the quad :

[quad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UziE.jpg)

Comment: First of all: Your `IEnumerator` doesn't `yield` at any point so currently it wouldn't even compile .. there should be at least a `yield return null;` within the `while` loop otherwise the entire movement happens in one single frame ... And then the question is how exactly is `rot` set to `true`? Maybe you get some concurrently running routines?

Comment: @derHugo I added by mistake old ver of the method I updated it now with the yield return null.

Comment: Your `Update` method is pretty huge and complex .. you should definitely split it up a bit ... I didn't parse it all but I'm pretty sure the issue might be that your condition is true multiple consequent frames so you get concurrent routines

Comment: @derHugo you right about it so I used a break point and then set stopped to false so it will not set rot to true all many times. So now it's executing the Coroutine ScaleOverSeconds once only but still the player is stuttering when moving. Without the moveTo part it will scale and rotate smooth with the moveTo it's stuttering.

Comment: Is there anything else moving it? E.g. is the `Animator` holding a keyframe somewhere on the position? It is enough that any animationClip of the `Animator` holds only one single keyframe on the position .. in this case the `Animator` gains full control over the position and altering it via code has no effect since the animator update is one of the last things executed before the frame is rendered ...

Comment: @derHugo I think I found the problem. When I'm using cinemachine freelook camera to lookat and follow the player the stuttering happens. now I just disabled both main camera with the brain and the freelook camera and added a simple regular camera and the new simple camera follow the player it's child of the player and the player is not stuttering. not sure what is the problem yet but something with the cinemachine camera make it.